# Publishing an App in the Google play store?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been exploring the AppInventor by Google and MIT. Does anyone know if you can publish your App using this or can you only download it to your personal device?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with app engine

Answer (score 0):

You could also upload / publish it on the Google Playstore.

There is a official FAQ:

http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/other/appstoplay.html